# Show multiple dialogs in loop one at a time => Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have jquery snippet that is working on a VF page in saleforce. I pass an array from a query result in SF to a method in a script that should show each array item as a unique dialog window. All the array elements should be looped through and only when the user closes the dialog, should it proceed to the next array element and create another dialog.

So far I got the jquery code running and it shows ONLY 1 dialog, the last one. After debugging I found that it is NOT stopping at each dialog so therefore all the messages are looped through non stop. If I use alert instead, it works fine showing each message in sequence. See code below, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
    //display the dialog window for each message
function showPopMessages(pPopMsgs){
    var updatedMsgs = new Array();
    console.log('updatedMsgs.legnth: '+pPopMsgs.length);
    $j.each( pPopMsgs, function( index, value ){
        console.log('updatedMsgs.value: '+value.Message__c);
        $j("#dialog-confirm").html(value.Message__c);
        $j( "#dialog-confirm" ).css("display","block");
        $j( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog(); //IIT IS NOT STOPPING HERE!!!
        //alert(value.Message__c);
    });
}
```

Comment: what is a VF page? what is your output to this code?

Comment: Sorry VF page is a visualforce page in salesforce.com. I dont get what you mean? output? The output would be the dialog window opening and "stopping" to show the desired message, then again for each message. The code runs fine, then gets the correct messages and passes that onto the div that will be the dialog. Then the dialog method is called on the div to make it a dialog window. The problem is as I have said, the loop does not stop at $j( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog(); so therefore I only see the last message, all the other ones are iterated over and overwritten(or something of the sort).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about jQuery UI, but it seems as though you aren't passing any arguments to the dialog(). That sounds like a recipe to make nothing happen. What happens if you just add `.dialog('wait');` ?

Of course, if you are getting errors in the console, we want to see those.

Comment: Thank you @changokun but 'wait' is not a dialog() method in jquery so cannot use that. I don't get any errors, I have done a console.log on all messages passed into the code and they are iterating correctly. The only problem is that the code is not stopping at each $j( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog();